# Python: error al almacenar una tupla

Tags: python, sqlite

Estoy intentando crear una función que me permita meter a modo de tupla los string de "piezas" en un query de SQLite. Para ello he creado anteriormente una base de datos que almacenan los valores de Piezas y Ordenes.
Después he creado esta función, que es donde tengo problemas.

```
    def orden_compra ():
        Vendedor_nombre = input('¿Quién eres?: ')
        numero = int(input('¿Número de artículos?: '))
        lista_piezas=[]
        for i in range (0, numero):
            while True:
                pieza_nombre = input('Nombre de la pieza a comprar: ')
                try:
                    pieza = Piezas.get(Piezas.Nombre == pieza_nombre)
                    break
                except DoesNotExist:
                    print('Esta pieza no existe actualmente en el sistema, '
                        'por favor ingresa un nombre correcto.')
            ID = input('ID de la compra: ')
            for precio in Piezas.select().where(Piezas.Nombre == pieza_nombre):
                precio_ordenes = (precio.Precio)
            precio_ordenes+=precio_ordenes
            pieza=str(pieza)
            lista_piezas.append(pieza)
            Ordenes.create(ID_compra_ordenes=ID, Fecha_compra_ordenes=datetime.now(),
                          Vendedor_ordenes=Vendedor_nombre, Piezas_ordenes = pieza_2,
                          Precio_ordenes=lista_piezas)
            print('Pieza vendida satisfactoreamente')
```

La función me pide un nombre y el número de artículos para registrar, mediante un loop me pide el nombre de la pieza y lo comprueba si existe ya previamente en la base de datos creada anteriormente (tabla Precio).

Si es así me pide más opciones del producto si no, me pide de nuevo que meta un nombre válido.
Cuando existe una concordancia entre el objeto a registrar y el que está almacenado en la base de datos de Precio obtiene el precio de esa tabla y va sumando los precios acorde con el número total de productos adquiridos.

Mi problema es que esta función registra objeto a objeto y me gustaría que el total de objetos que una persona registre se queden almacenados a modo de tupla. Para ello he hecho uso de la función append, como pueden ver y me da error:

```
           Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "C:/Users/apl00.DESKTOP-IGEQ9D2/Desktop/CloudStation/Proyectos/Python/Módulos/Proyecto_final/Proyecto_main.py", line 214, in <module>
orden_compra()
         File "C:/Users/apl00.DESKTOP-IGEQ9D2/Desktop/CloudStation/Proyectos/Python/Módulos/Proyecto_final/Proyecto_main.py", line 112, in orden_compra
Ordenes.create(ID_compra_ordenes=ID, Fecha_compra_ordenes=datetime.now(),
          TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

En qué estoy fallando?
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En el momento que haces `pieza=str(pieza)` creas un objeto de tipo "texto" que en realidad es una tupla de caracteres y por ende inmutable. En la siguiente linea intentas añadir más caracteres a esa tupla y te falla. Haz una copia de esa tupla nueva o crea otro tipo de objeto como una lista por ejemplo.

EDIT: Ejemplo ilustrativo:

```
In [1]: texto = "pieza"

In [2]: lista = []

In [3]: lista.append(texto)

In [4]: lista
Out[4]: ['pieza']
```

Comment: Gracías Jose, sin embargo cuando hago la modificación que me dices         pieza=str(pieza) 
pieza_2=pieza.append()  
Ordenes.create(ID_compra_ordenes=ID, Fecha_compra_ordenes=datetime.now(), Vendedor_ordenes=Vendedor_nombre, Piezas_ordenes = pieza_2, Precio_ordenes=precio_ordenes)  
me genera el mismo error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' ¿En qué estoy fallando?

Comment: he modificado la pregunta añadiendo la modificación que me has dicho

Comment: Pero sigues haciendo lo mismo. El tema es que en la linea `pieza=pieza.append(pieza)` lo que hace son dos operaciones: Primero intentas añadir la tupla pieza a sí misma y luego intentas asignar el resultado a pieza otra vez. Esa doble operacion no es necesaria, porque `append()` ya añadiria tu resultado, pero no lo hace porque la tupla no se puede modificar. Sin embargo si que puedes hacer `lista = []` y luego `lista.append(pieza)`

Comment: Perfecto Jose, ese error me lo ha subsanado. Ahora entiendo mejor como funciona la función append. Siin embargo ahora me devuelve otro error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/apl00.DESKTOP-IGEQ9D2/Desktop/CloudStation/Proyectos/Python/Módulos/Proyecto_final/Proyecto_main.py", line 214, in <module>
    orden_compra()
  File "C:/Users/apl00.DESKTOP-IGEQ9D2/Desktop/CloudStation/Proyectos/Python/Módulos/Proyecto_final/Proyecto_main.py", line 112, in orden_compra
    Ordenes.create(ID_compra_ordenes=ID, Fecha_compra_ordenes=datetime.now(), ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: he modificado la pregunta de nuevo con tu aclaración. De nuevo gracias por explicarmelo

Comment: Parece que se te ha truncado la salida de error y falta el final que es lo importante :)

Comment: Tienes razón, lo siento, es que soy nuevo en este lenguaje y aún se me escapa. Ya he modificado la pregunta

Comment: No estoy seguro pero creo que quizás deberías abrir otra pregunta porque el fallo nuevo no se corresponde con el titulo de la pregunta y al final lo que importa es que todo el mundo pueda encontrar este tipo de problemas. De cualquier forma el fallo ocurre porque la funcion create espera una variable de texto, un numero o un array de bytes, y le has pasado la lista. Creo que es más un problema de concepto. `Create`crea una unica entrada, y si le da una lista (aunque sea de un solo elemento) se "ralla" y no sabe qué es lo que quieres añadir. Un workaround sería `lista_piezas[0]` en su lugar

Comment: Genial ! Voy a crear un post nuevo con la nueva pregunta. Muchas gracias @Jose Rodriguez